# How to properly insert documents into a collection using the MongoDB Web Shell

Tags: mongodb

I am having some trouble inserting a collection of documents into a MongoDB Web Shell from the mongodb site.

The link provided: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/

Here is what I have for a simple example:

```
db.FirstExample.insertMany ([ 

    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Airfare", "Amount": "500.34" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Hotel", "Amount": "200" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Taxi Fare", "Amount": "100.00" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Long Distance Phone Charges", "Amount": "57.89" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Food",  "Amount": "82.19" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-02", "Description": "Food",  "Amount": "17.89" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-02", "Description": "Personal Items", "Amount": "32.54" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-03", "Description": "Taxi Fare", "Amount": "75.00" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-03", "Description": "Food",  "Amount": "36.45" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-03", "Description": "New Suit", "Amount": "750.00" } 
]);
```

When I run this collection into the MongoDB Web Shell, it works perfectly. Now here's the trouble, I want to include one more element called "ExpenseItem". When I enter the new code snippet, I get an error.

```
db.FirstExample.insertMany ([ 

    { "ExpenseItem:"

    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Airfare", "Amount": "500.34" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Hotel", "Amount": "200" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Taxi Fare", "Amount": "100.00" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Long Distance Phone Charges", "Amount": "57.89" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Food",  "Amount": "82.19" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-02", "Description": "Food",  "Amount": "17.89" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-02", "Description": "Personal Items", "Amount": "32.54" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-03", "Description": "Taxi Fare", "Amount": "75.00" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-03", "Description": "Food",  "Amount": "36.45" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-03", "Description": "New Suit", "Amount": "750.00" } 

    } 
]);
```

The error is this: 
**E QUERY [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :**

Why am I getting the error? Isn't the ":" already next to the "ExpsenseItem"? What key detail am I missing for this code snippet not running in the MongoDb Web Shell?

Comment: Not valid JSON.

Comment: Do you want to add `ExpenseItem` to each doc you are inserting or do you want a single `ExpenseItem` to be an array containing all the date/description/amount subdocs?

Comment: A single ExpenseItem to be an Array containing all the date/description/amount subdocs.

Answer (score 1):

The colon separating they key `ExpenseItem` from the rest of the document is inside the quotes so is considered part of the key. To nest the documents as they are you would need to put them inside an array. As so:

```
{ "ExpenseItem" : [

    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Airfare", "Amount": "500.34" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Hotel", "Amount": "200" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Taxi Fare", "Amount": "100.00" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Long Distance Phone Charges", "Amount": "57.89" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-01", "Description": "Food",  "Amount": "82.19" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-02", "Description": "Food",  "Amount": "17.89" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-02", "Description": "Personal Items", "Amount": "32.54" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-03", "Description": "Taxi Fare", "Amount": "75.00" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-03", "Description": "Food",  "Amount": "36.45" },
    { "Date": "2001-01-03", "Description": "New Suit", "Amount": "750.00" }
]
}
```

This document will insert but it is now a single document.